# Resizing listbox badly in custom UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, anchor, dock

I made custom control and i want listbox to be at the bottom of it . Like on picture bellow:

[image]

Only thing that i did is that i set dock property to bottom. And that do my job , but soon i realised that , when im resizing my control vertically , listbox is not resizing well.

Here is picture 
[image]

Background color of my control is red , so listbox is not resizing well, i dont know why, but if i move control one more pixel down, the listbox would be moved nicely, but if i continue to move, it is same.

**I discovered that every 11 pixels listbox resizes well, but on 12th , control is resizing , but listbox doesnt , again**

Anybody knows why?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
Always __TAG__ your question correctly! - I can't reproduce. Dock.Bottom should always keep it at the bottom, IntegralHeight  true or false. Did you turn Docking off again?

Comment: Have you tried to use the resize event to resize the listBox with it ?

Comment: @Taw Winforms in this case

Comment: Of course. But to see this from the questions page you need to TAG it!

Comment: @TaW did it :) sorry for missunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is WinForms, check the IntegralHeight property on the listbox. When true, the listbox height will always be a multiple of the item height, which is probably what's causing the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Dock.Bottom should always keep it at the bottom, IntegralHeight true or false.